# Mobile menu not showing

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

Hello the site is http://vs.avischulman.com/

the parent theme is http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=mystile

I made changes to menu, but just neg top margin, border, and background.

On the demo it has 2 mobile menus. But it they don't show on my site. and i'm not sure what could have made them go missing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to bring back the toggle nav you need to remove the declaration below:

line 77 of style.css

```
hgroup {
    display: none !important;  /* remove this declaration */
}
```

For the other one - I think you may have removed the select tags in your header file - but they aren't showing at all.